# How can I condition my router details to show me all the id's?

Tags: mysql, node.js, router

In this router it managed to show only a specific id, but within that id I would like to show the others that I have in my database.

```
router.get('/detalles/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    conexion.query('SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE id=?', [id], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            res.render('detalles', { noticias: results[0], results: results });
        
        }
    });
});
```

[At the top I only need the details of a specific id, below I want to show the others.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dirWA.png)

Comment: "*within that id*" What is considered "*within*" an identifier value? "*I would like to show the others that I have in my database*" Doesn't this defeat the purpose of `GET`ting a single `id`? Why not just have a `GET` handler on the `/detalles` route (without an `id` URL parameter) to handle listing of "*others that [you] have in [your] database*"?

Answer (score -1):

What I would recommend you is to do a "Get All" route which means that you will take every id. It think it will look like this.
! Warning ! Don't forget to put it before you route '/detalles/:id' to avoid conflict between them so it will not call /detalles/:id without any id.

```js
router.get('/detalles/', (req, res) => {
    conexion.query('SELECT * FROM noticias', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            res.render('detalles', { noticias: results, results: results });
        }
    });
});
```